# Edit the value of a field in MS word365 (16.0)

Tags: ms-word

I am struggling with a word docx template from my company, and I would like to change the value of a field. As simple as that. I can't publish the document, it's company data.

The fields in the editor appear as a custom text like `<INSERT document title here>` (I'm sure that text is custom written by my company, because it appears in french). Using right-click > toggle field codes changes that text to (for example) `{ DOCPROPERTY "MonTitre" \* MERGEFORMAT }`

There is another instance of that field (same field code) somewhere else on the document that I can use to check the value of that field.

My problem is simple: I want to assign a value to that field, just the way i'm expected to fill that document template. In other words, I want to follow the most simple user story possible with fields, and I already lost half an hour searching.

I tried selecting the whole line then type, click once then type, navigate in the right click menu, refresh the whole document referencs with F9... Nothing can make the two instances of that field display the document title.

What did I miss? How did the Microsoft UX specialists think the user would want to do when they see "type the document title here"?

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers). In any event, instead of trying to edit the field code, you should be editing the 'MonTitre' Document Property. See under File|Info>Prperties>Advanced Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the hidden company lore:

The field values are hidden behind `File > Info > Properties > advanced Properties`. this brings a popup below where you can add new fields and change their values. Don't forget to click `Add` or `Modify` for each value you want to update

[image: screenshot]